# Update enum using Reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I have declared an enum

```
enum Animal {
    Cat("Tom"), Rat("Jerry");
}
```

I have to add test cases on the values. Is there a way to add another Animal Type on the go using reflection in enum, for which I have to fail the test case.

P.S. These values have some resemblance with another module runs parallel on server, so in future if some other coder updates enum, to ensure he has to make those changes in another module as well.
So, I am adding a functional test case around it.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue161.html

Comment: There is no sense in creating such a testcase for the testcase. Even if you can prove that the testcase will fail on that hacked `enum`, it does not prove that it will fail on an improperly extended `enum`.

Comment: Hey Pankaj, please mark my answer as answer if it resolved your question

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks, your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

All the values in an enum should be known upfront. In this case, you can also write a test case which 'gets' all the values from this enum and asserts that the size is 2 , values are as expected etc. On a separate note, having duplicate enums in two modules which should remain in sync seems like a design/architecture smell. May be both modules should pick up these values from a shared db or a shared cache to properly mitigate this.